# Reducing a relative adverb in a relative clause

Tags: grammar

Can I ever reduce **relative** **adverbs**, i.e. *where, when or why*, in relative clauses?

I've read somewhere that we can reduce *where* if it follows "the place/somewhere/anywhere/anywhere/nowhere", but reducing *where* preceded by *the place* doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: There are essentially two options, both correct: "the place where we stayed last year" / "the place we stayed last year". Some speakers also allow "the place that we stayed last year".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in conversation it would be natural to say "the place I lived for 5 years" meaning "the place **where** I lived for 5 years". Omitting "where" could be seen as slightly informal.

Comment: Thank you! Is it too informal to be used in writing?

Comment: Not necessarily. From a work of fiction: "At that time he knew only vaguely that Hell was __a place you did not want to go__, like the dark basement or the even darker attic."